# How to check what is the latest version of an artifact available in nexus repository?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have a java desktop app and a launcher that check if a newer version is available, or it will do that. But I can't figure out how to check out if an update (a newer version of the artifact) is available through  the nexus api.

Also, I can't download the latest version. I tried the below url but I'm getting a 404.

This works: `http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=io.github.bonigarcia&a=webdrivermanager&v=LATEST`

This not: `http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=maven-group&g=io.github.bonigarcia&a=webdrivermanager&v=LATEST`

This artifact is just an example, it exists on my repository
`http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/maven-group/io/github/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/1.7.0/webdrivermanager-1.7.0.pom`

I don't understand what is going on. What I'm missing?
Note: Nexus version 3.4.0-02 (I have to update yet)